# Cannot fetch data from localhost using Svelte

Tags: fastapi, svelte

I am trying to study svelte and fastapi. But svelte can't fetch fastapi backend.

My Network is:
Asus Router - synology NAS - synology's docker

synology's docker have fastapi and svelte server.

---

fastapi code is:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    return {"message": "hello."}
```

---

svelte code is:

```
<script>
  let message;

  fetch("http://localhost:12123/hello").then((response) => {
    response.json().then((json) => {
      message = json.message;
    });
  });
</script>

<h1>{message}, testing</h1>
```

---

docker is Linux system.
fastapi run: `uvicorn main:app --reload --port=12123`
svelte run: `npm run dev`

svelte setting is:

```
jsconfig.json -> "checkJs": false
package.json -> "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0 --port 51733",
```

npm version is 8.19.4
node js version is v16.20.0

result is: `undefined, testing`
If I open fastapi, svelte can fetch from `http://domain(fastapi)`

What am I missing, where is the problem?

Comment: `http://localhost:12123/hello` will always refer to the computer the browser is running on - it seems like this is a different computer than the one where you're running your applications (which you are running on docker on the synology). You probably want to use the host of the synology instance (the one where you're loading your content from instead)?

Comment: I used bing.com to translate it. There may be errors. Thank you for your answer. I finally found the problem that lasted for a few days. I just found out that svelte checks the IP based on the browser running svelte. Thank you very much. While experiencing various failures due to this problem for several days, my head was very complicated, but the problem was solved in just one word. Then I wonder if there is a way for svelte to fetch by referring to the internal IP of the running server. Is it possible to fetch by referring to the internal IP?